# Rails conditional association based on options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to figure out how to conditionally associate 2 tables based on which option the user choose.  For example:

Model shop belongs to shop kind in shop kind have 3 options that is vintage, independent label and retailer.
If the user choose independent label will associate with independent brand model.

Comment: There's no way to have some instances associated and some not. But usually this is find. Just make the association from `Shop` to `IndepentBrand`. If the `shop.kind` is not `independent label` then you can ignore the association in your code. There's no reason an association has to be *populated* even though it is *defined*.

Comment: sorry gwcoffey! i did not get it, so i can't use true/false method?

Comment: I added an answer that uses a normal association, and then validations to make sure there is/is not an associated brand as appropriate. let me know if I'm not getting what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can model the association like normal. You can then use validations to ensure that the `independent_brand` is or is not applied as appropriate. Something like this:

```
class IndependentBrand < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :independent_brand

   validates :independent_brand, {
      :presence => {if: :independent_brand?},
      :absence => {unless: :independent_brand?}
   }

   def independent_brand?
      self.kind == "independent_brand"
   end
end
```